# PHP soap url - blank content

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I have a working soap webservice built on php; which shows below output when accessed through web browser.

But when i have migrated the same code to a different server, the same URL shows blank page. How this is possible ?

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope><SOAP-ENV:Body><SOAP-ENV:Fault><faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode><faultstring>Bad Request. Can't find HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA</faultstring></SOAP-ENV:Fault></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: Whats the server error log say?

Comment: I have checked the apache logs, there are no errors shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If code works differently on different servers, it's because of differences between the servers.

- Check the web server error log
- Check the PHP error log
- Check the version of PHP that is installed
- Check that all the required PHP extensions are installed

Comment: Webservice related port was blocked by firewall; however, no apache errors shown.